# Where did my rep come from?

Tags: support, reputation, openid, linked-accounts

So not more than 10 minutes ago I had 964 rep:

[image]

I then signed up for programmers.stackexchange.
Within this process I may have linked another openid to my account (is there a way to see all associated openids?)

Then I returned to stackoverflow to find I had gained 100 rep:

[image]

Nothing has changed on my history, and it wasn't from [having another account go over 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100279/rep-when-an-account-on-a-different-site-reaches-a-number) because none of my accounts have gone over 200 in nearly a year.

My activity feed doesn't shed any light on the situation, so my question is:

Where did the rep come from?

Not that I'm complaining or anything....

Comment: What does [your reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) say?

Comment: That only raises more questions.

Comment: Your link has my rep at 1079.  I have 1064 on my bar still.

Comment: Well now I'm at 1079 after hitting the recalculation.  Caching maybe?

Comment: You are the lucky winner of today's draw. :-)

Comment: *"Where did my rep come from?"* When a question and an answer love each other very much...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you signed up for another StackExchange site. When you have > 200 rep, the first time you join another SE site and associate the two accounts together, you get +100 rep to both accounts.

You had over 200 rep already on SO, so when you joined Programmers, you got the bonus instantly.

Each account can only ever get the bonus once, so if you sign up for Puzzles & Code Golf, your PCG account will start at 101, but your SO account **won't** get another bonus since you already have the +100 for joining Programmers.

Edit: Is it possible your SO, SU, and Meta accounts didn't know about each other yet? Maybe you had those accounts, but they weren't associated with each other across Stack Exchange. You only get the bonus when you link your accounts together on both sites, so if you've had those other accounts since before that feature got implemented, it might not have happened automatically.

Comment: But I already had signed up for another site.  I have profiles on SuperUser, and Meta.

Comment: @James - See edit. What's your SO user ID?

Comment: @James: I can't explain why it never happened before, but it's definitely the reason. I had a look in your user history to confirm. It shows that you "associated account on Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow, Reputation = 100".

Comment: @mmyers So i got the bonus by linking my SO account to my SO account?